# how can I do pandas dataframe 'decadal resample' over a 'structured' or even 10 years?

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched for a while, but nothing related to my question is found.
So I post a new thread.

I have a simple dataset which is read in by pandas as dataframe, with some daily data starting on 1951-08-01, ending on 2018-10-01.
Now I want to down-sample the data to decadal mean, so I can simply do df.resample('10A').mean()['some data'].
This gives me 8 data points, which are at 1951-12, 1961-12, 1971-12, 1981-12, 1991-12, 2001-12, 2011-12, 2021-12. This indicates that the decadal mean values are calculated for year 1951 separately, years 1952-1961, 1962-1971, etc.

I wonder if it is possible to calculate the decadal mean values every 'structured' 10 years?
for example, the decadal mean values are calculated betwen 1950-1959, 1960-1969, 1970-1979, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the decade separately and group on that:

```py
decade = df['Date'].dt.year.floordiv(10).mul(10)
df.groupby(decade)['Value'].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you! It is fantastic to have the 'decade' years. However, using df.groupby(decade)['Value'].mean() doesn't work directly. One more step to make things work, set 'decade' as a new column in the dataframe and make that column as index. Then we can use df.groupby[decade]. Thank you very much!